# Output razor string inside a string literal quotations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

How do I do this:

```
<tr id="paymentId_@item.ItemId">
```

I want the output to look like:

```
<tr id="paymentId_0">
```

when `item.ItemId` is 0.

Comment: what was the syntax to generate `<tr id="paymentId_@item.ItemId">` ?

Comment: Bala R, I typed that. I just loop over some table rows and output some info.

Comment: BTW, it's not working because Razor thinks it's an email address.  It;s got nothing to do with the attribute.

Comment: you just need to be explicit in that case

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
<tr id="paymentId_@(item.ItemId)">
```