# How to end code inside a string?

Tags: c#

I know this is basic, but I'm feeling there's got to be a better way to do this.

I have a dynamic file name:

```
/img/car-1.jpg
/img/car-2.jpg
/img/car-3.jpg
```

In my Model View, I want to do this:

```
<img src="/img/car-@Model.Number.jpg" />
```

Unfortunately the compiler considers the `.jpg` to be part of the code, and says `'int' does not contain a definition for jpg`.

I also tried this:

```
<img src="/img/car-@{Model.Number}.jpg" />
```

But it gives me this error: `'System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPafe<TModel>.Model' is a 'property' but is used like a 'type'`.

So for now I use a string builder at the top of the page, but it seems so verbose for such a simple issue. How can I tell C# "I'm done with this `@` code section?"

Edit: a suggestion said my question was like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8776641/c-sharp-razor-syntax-inside-a-string), so here's how it's different: I am using the solution to that question in my code example, and still getting an error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Razor Syntax inside a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8776641/c-sharp-razor-syntax-inside-a-string)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Output razor string inside a string literal quotations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6206999/output-razor-string-inside-a-string-literal-quotations)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try parenthesis `(` `)`

```
<img src="/img/car-@(Model.Number).jpg" />
```

Take a look here [C# Razor Syntax Quick Reference](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx/)

Comment: Why is it that parenthesis work in this case, but not braces - which work in most other cases?

Answer (score 4):

Try using a String.Format as your source:

```
 <img src="@String.Format("/img/car-{0}.jpg", Model.Number)" />
```